# Read-only cross origin domain request

Tags: domains, javascript, security, xss

Is it possible to allow read-only access in a CORS header?  I want JS from two websites to be capable of verifying each other, but not altering each other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this is no, there is no way to make resources on a page read-only to JavaScript loaded from another domain.

Comment: I'm not sure who voted this down but it is correct, I wasted a great deal of time trying to make it work.

Comment: I think nobody knows what do you mean by read-only. Javascript can never alter server (or local except local storage) files, so whatever you retrieve is readonly unless you create server (or local) API to save the changes javascript has made. That being said, both your answer and question are quite unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by read-only in this case, because it does depend on the web application using the HTTP-methods/verbs correctly, but this might help:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```